# How to delete all lines that do NOT contain a certain word in Vim?

Tags: vim, regex, find-and-replace

In vim I can delete all lines that contain the word "price" with this

```
:g /price/d
```

How can I delete all lines that do NOT contain the word "price"?

Answer (score 318, accepted):

You can use

`:g!/price/d`

to delete every line that doesn't contain "price"

As answered below, `g!` is an alias to `v`. this is equivalent to

`:v/price/d`

Comment: I knew it would be easy...

Comment: `:g!` is also known as `:v` (akin to `grep -v`).

Comment: What does the `%` do?

Comment: `%` is a special range in this context that means the whole file. See `:help cmdline-ranges`.

Comment: `%` is optional since the default range is the entire buffer.

Comment: The percetage sign is redundant.  The "g" already selects all lines.  A simple  :g!/price/d  will delete all lines without "price" in them.

Comment: What about if we want to delete lines that **do** have "price" but **do not** have "cost"? Alternatively, what if we want to delete lines that do not have "cost" **or** do not have "paper" (where "or" is the [inclusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction#Classical_disjunction) one).

Comment: I don't know of a great way to do this short of using external tools like `grep` and `sed`

Answer (score 51):

You can also use:

`:v/price/d`

to delete lines.

Comment: Fwiw -- Looks like [`g` is for "global" and `v` for "inverse"](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_g) (if you believe what you read on vim.famdom).

Comment: `help :v` in vim confirms it

Answer (score 14):

```
%!grep "price"
```

is another option that can be considerably faster than `:v` for large files.

Tested on Vim 7.4, Ubuntu 14.04, 1M line log file.

Lines that contain word: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725265/how-can-i-delete-all-lines-that-do-not-begin-with-certain-characters/42714334#42714334

Comment: Super fast and a marvelous solution