# Remove lines not containing a word in Vim

Tags: vim, regex, find-and-replace

In Vim I often find I'm only interested in lines containing a certain string of text and want to delete all other lines.

It's easy to match lines containing a string:

```
:s/^.*foo.*\n//
```

What I normally end up doing is two passes, one to "flag" all the lines I want with a special first character:

```
:s/^\(.*foo.*\)$/X\1/
```

And in the second pass it's easy to do a negative match for one character in a fixed position, so I delete all the lines without my string thus:

```
:s/^[^X].*\n//
```

But isn't there a much more straightforward way to do this with just a single pass? What am I missing?

Comment: I think this has been asked before despite my not finding it at the time: [vim delete all lines that do NOT contain a certain word](http://superuser.com/questions/265085)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would delete all lines that don't contain `foo`.

```
:g/^\(.*foo\)\@!.*$/d
```

Instead, you could also use `:v` to reverse the sense of search pattern.

```
:v/\(foo\)/d
```

You can read more about the way `:g` and `:v` work [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g).

And more on defining ranges, use of metacharacters etc. for search and replace [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace).

Comment: It seems `:g` is one of very many vim commands I never learned before - thanks! `(-:`

Comment: Why `\(` and `\)`?

Comment: `+`, `?`, `|`, `{`, `}`, `(`, and `)` must be escaped to use their special function.

Comment: I use `:g` and `:v` a lot. If, for some reason, `:v` doesn't stick you can use `:g!`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your aim is only to remove the lines with the text, that can be easily done with awk like so :

```
awk '/regex/{print}' filename
```

Meaning awk will act on filename. You can either pipe it to a new filename or the same filename, like this -

```
   awk '/regex/{print}' filename > filename.tmp && mv filename.tmp filename
```

Comment: While I do have vim installed on every platform I use, I usually only have awk when I'm on *nix. Lately I'm mostly on Windows. Hence I seek a vim-based answer. Thanks though.

Comment: I just realised that my initial solution wouldn't work... so if you do every use this, you should do it this way!